# Minimum cost of buying K items from N stacks with different prices

Tags: algorithm

There are N stacks of boxes of some items.

**Each box:** Can have different number of items.
          Can have a different cost per item.

You have to buy K units of items.
All boxes are stacked up meaning you can only buy from the top and move your way down.

How can you optimally buy K items so that the total cost is minimized?
*(We can assume you can buy a partial box)*

**EXAMPLE 1:**

StackA = [1, 4], [2, 3], [5, 1] ,[10, 50], [1, 5]

StackB = [4, 1], [6, 7], [2, 3] ,[14, 7], [6, 1], [19, 4]

K = 10

***where*** [x, y] = [number of items in the box, cost per item]

Optimal BUYs would be:

StackA = Buy 2 complete boxes from and the third one partially from the top =>
    (**1**x4=4), (**2**x3=6), (**3**x1=3) = cost = **13**

StackB = Buy first box =>
    (**4**x1=4) => cost = 4

**Total minimum cost for buying 10 items would be 4 + 13 = 17**

**EXAMPLE 2:**

StackA = [1, 100], [100, 1]

StackB = [10, 1], [6, 15], [25, 30] ,[15, 2], [60, 1], [19, 4]

K = 80

Optimal BUYs would be:

StackA = Buy 1 whole box and buy 79 from the second =>
    (**1**x100=100), (**79**x1=79), = cost = 179

**Total minimum cost for buying 80 items would be 179**

Answer (score 0):

**Pre-process:**

Make an array `cost` for each stack, length `K`, where `cost[i]` is the cost of buying the top `i` items from that stack.

**Compute:**

define a recursive ...

```
function stack_cost(stack_list, limit, subtotal)
// stack_list    list of stacks and cost array of each
// limit         remaining quantity of items to buy
// subtotal      cost so far

best_cost = +Inf

for quant in range [0:limit]
    // Buy the top "quant" items from this stack,
    //    and move on to the next.
    total = stack_cost(stack_list[1: ],
                       limit - quant,
                       subtotal + stack_list[0].cost[quant])
    if total < best_cost
        total = best_cost
        // save solution as needed
```

Note that will benefit from dynamic programming in this: memoize the minimum cost for a given limit and stack position.

**OPTIMIZATION**

I think you'll find a more efficient attack by bisecting the stack and incrementally finding the best solution for `quant` items on the left and `limit-quant` items on the right, for `quant` iterating through the allowed range.  This allows you to recur by bisection, and gives you paths to make incremental estimates for one-item changes.  You can memoize partial results from the bottom up, finding the optimal solution in lesser time complexity.